# is there any way to create savepoint without using transaction?

Tags: sql-server, save

I have some queries such as update, delete.. etc.

Before i run them i want to create savepoint (without using transaction). But "how?" I don't know because savepoint is part of transaction. Is there another way to achieve this job?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by having a savepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** there is no way to create a [save point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx) without a transaction.

In absence of a transaction the concept is meaningless.

If you are looking at reducing locking that will be generated due to the transaction, have a look at [snapshot isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130975.aspx).